# Office.js API for PowerPoint (Preview)

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, ms-office, office-js

I am trying to use the new Office.js API for Powerpoint which is currently in preview. I am unable to get anything working with the PowerPoint.run() method call because it seems to behave differently that the ones in Excel and Word. Could anyone help me find a working way to call the SlideCollection.getCount() method referenced here?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerpoint/powerpoint.slidecollection?view=powerpoint-js-preview

Sample code (assumed I needed to load items first before trying to get the count):

```
PowerPoint.run(function (context) {
  var properties = context.presentation.slides.items;
  context.load(properties);
  return context.sync()
    .then(function() {
      console.log(properties);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a call to slides.getCount() which should work

```
PowerPoint.run(async (context) => {
    context.presentation.load("slides");
    await context.sync();

    var slides = context.presentation.slides;
    var slideCount = slides.getCount();
    await context.sync();

    console.log("There are ", slideCount.value, " slides in this presentation");
}
```

Comment: No need to load all the properties of all the slides as we are only interested in the slide count, which is obtain via a getter (which is not a property). You can safely drop ``context.presentation.load("slides"); await context.sync();``

Answer (score 0):

```
PowerPoint.run(async function (context) {
  context.presentation.load("slides");
  await context.sync();
  const slide = context.presentation.slides.getItemAt(0);
  slide.load("id");//you just load any property from PPT object model and then sync
  await context.sync();
  console.log(slide.id);
});
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.